# Postgresql: change default data path

Tags: server, startup, postgresql

I would like to point the PostgreSQL server to a particular non-default data directory upon startup.  Right now, I have to (either manually or in a script) use `pg_ctl` to stop and restart the database with my `/new/path/to/data`.

A second related question:  is there a place in the Ubuntu file system I can start looking when I have questions about what is being run at startup?

Thanks

Comment: You should ask the second question as a separate question, as its quite pointed and definitely interesting!

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards